# vb.net combobox selectedvalue event error

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I've got this error "Operator '=' is not defined for type 'CivilStatus' and type 'Integer'."

Code:

```
Private Sub cboCivilStatus_SelectedValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboCivilStatus.SelectedValueChanged

    If cboCivilStatus.SelectedValue = 2 Then
        dtpDateMarried.Enabled = True
    Else
        dtpDateMarried.Enabled = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you should try using the Combobox SelectedIndexChanged Event

```
Private Sub cboCivilStatus_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboCivilStatus.SelectedIndexChanged
        If cboCivilStatus.Text = "2" Then
            dtpDateMarried.Enabled = True
        Else
            dtpDateMarried.Enabled = False
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the selectedtext it did not enable the dtpDateMarried control. What event should i put the code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `SelectedValue` contains an object of class `CivilStatus`. If you're looking for Index of the selected item, use `cboCivilStatus.SelectedIndex` property instead:

```
If cboCivilStatus.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
```

But if you need a property of `CivilStatus` you need to check against that property, e.g.

```
If CType(cboCivilStatus.SelectedValue, CivilStatus).MyIntProperty = 2 Then
```

Comment: I got this error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.int64' to type 'ChurchData.CivilStatus'"

Comment: Just to clarify - do you need to check for 2nd element in the dropdown or for element with specific property = 2?

Comment: I just I want to enable the datetime picker control if the selected value of the combobox =2. The combobox is bound to civilstatus class. In the database CivilStatus = 'Married', ID = 2.

Comment: Can you put breakpoint at the IF statemnt, add `cboCivilStatus.SelectedValue` to the WATCH and see what it is equal to and what properties it has?

Comment: Watch 1: Name: cboCivilStatus.SelectedValue Long, Value: 2{Long} 2, Type: Object Long

Comment: Weird if i put the original code to a button click event. The code runs fine. :-(